# Image is going out of the screen in android

Tags: android, bitmap

I draw a picture by using BitmapFactory...The Content is The picture will listen the accelerometer.. and move according to that...i write the code and it working perfectly...but the image is going out of the screen...the picture should be in the screen and visible to the user at all times....

Please tell me how to solve this...

```
mWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
            mHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
            float mRange = s.getMaximumRange();

            //
            // Convert MetersToPixels
            // metersToPixels = mWidth / .0254f
            //

            float startX = mWidth / (0.0254f * mRange);
            float startY = mHeight / (0.0254f * mRange);

            Canvas canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
            float mPosY = sensorY * startY;
            float mPosX = sensorX * startX;


            if (mPosX > mHorizontalBound) {
                mPosX = mHorizontalBound;
            }
            if (mPosY > mVerticalBound) {
                mPosY = mVerticalBound;
            }

            canvas.drawBitmap(betty, mPosY, mPosX, null);
            ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }

@Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        mXOrigin = (w - betty.getWidth()) * 0.5f;
        mYOrigin = (h - betty.getHeight()) * 0.5f;
        mHorizontalBound = ((w / mMetersToPixelsX) * 0.5f);
        mVerticalBound = ((h / mMetersToPixelsY) * 0.5f);
    }

}
```

The image is going out side of the screen..But it should not go like this...

Comment: what values does your bound variables have?

Comment: I can see that but I was asking for the mHorizontalBound and mVerticalBound variables...

Comment: These are the screen bounds..

Comment: first of all: no code in the comment, put it in the question itself. second: you still haven't answered my question.

Comment: The bound variables should have screen bounds....

Answer (score 0):

You need to check all four sides of your canvas.

You can try this:

```
int boundRight = canvas.getClipBounds().right; 
int boundLeft = canvas.getClipBounds().left;
int boundBottom = canvas.getClipBounds().bottom;
int boundTop= canvas.getClipBounds().top;

if ( mPosX > boundRight )  {
   mPosX = boundRight;
}  else if ( mPosX < boundLeft )  {
   mPosX = boundLeft;
}

if ( mPosY > boundBottom )  {
   mPosY = boundBottom
}  else if ( mPosY < boundTop )  {
   mPosY = boundTop;
}
```

Comment: Thank you it is working but it not working for bottom...and right side  image is moving up to center....

Comment: This is working only for...left and top Postions only...Beacuse in
canvas.drawBitmap(betty, left, top, null);

Comment: Simply add the size to the check for bottom/right, ie. `if ( mPosX + width > boundRight )` and `if ( mPosY + height > boundBottom )`.